# How to limit user requests per hour in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, laravel-5

I have a site that has few request options (for example add friend). I want to limit of requests made by use per certain time, for example so he can't send more than 5 friend requests within hour.

**QUESTION** How Can I achieve this?

**I have written following query**

```
$result = DB::table('bubble_users')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                     ->where('status', '=', "pending")
                     ->where('user_id','=', $user_id)
                     ->where(DB::raw('DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) > NOW()'))
                     ->groupBy('status')
                     ->get();
```

But I'm not getting wrong response

Anybody help me!!

Comment: You can use the throttle package for this. [read here](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle).

Comment: No , I can't use Throttle package as it will restrict users to wait till 1 hour completes.I want user to be waited for 1 hour to send 6th request(if 5 requests have been made in previous 1 hour)

Comment: Forget about the laravel bit for now. Instead consider providing a sample data set and desired result given a variety of timestamps.

Comment: @lakshmaji, You can change the time and number of request in Throttle config file.

Comment: if `3 out of 5` request been approved, would user able to send friend request in same hour ? actually you used `status = 'pending'` thats why

Comment: No ,the user cannot send friend request in same hour .I added one more status condition with **status ='active'** .Is it right way to doing it @Qazi

Comment: well, if you are just counting the friend request in same hour, then adding status condition does not make sense. better to remove. and also group by status too

Answer (score 1):

Just get last row of this user on table and get `created_at` column?

Then make another query to get count requests by this user in the our on the last 'created_at`query value.

So you can know if this our has 1, 2, 3, 4 or five requests.

Is very simple. ;)